# XAML in WPF to tiff or eps

Tags: xaml, printing

I am wondering if it is possible to create tiff/eps image from XAML in WPF.

We are looking for printing high resolution images from existing XAML in WPF.

Please let me know if you have any suggestions.

Comment: IMHO, this is a SU (http://superuser.com/) question, not a StackOverflow one.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what exactly you're trying to do you might want to look at the xsl-fo stuff. The goal of creating printable markup is the same but fo uses xml instead of xaml. Depending on your requirements you might be able to create xsl-fo directly instead of xaml. If not, I'm pretty sure you can find xaml to svg translators (there are lots that go from svg to xaml) and I know that xsl-fo can handle svg. For the last step of taking the xsl-fo to tiff I've used the Ecrion software but I'm sure there are others by now that also do a good job. Hope that helps...